# JUnit 5 assertThat не импортируется

Tags: rest, eclipse, импорт, junit

Хочу написать тесты для простенького `REST` приложения с использованием `JUnit` версии 5.10.1 в `Eclipse`. Пишу тесты впервые. Не получается импортировать метод `assertThat`:
при наведении на метод выдается либо следующая ошибка:

```
The method assertThat(String, not(equalTo(analysisServiceImpl.takeEntriesCount("daaabbbbbcc")))) is undefined for the type AnalysisServiceImplTest
```

Либо, если добавить этот предлагаемый импорт:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```

То следующая:

```
The method assertThat(String) in the type Assertions is not applicable for the arguments (String, not(equalTo(analysisServiceImpl.takeEntriesCount("daaabbbbbcc"))))
```

Пробовал и добавлять вышеуказанный импорт, и убирать - только ошибки разные.

Этот импорт, я так понял, не тот, что нужен, но при том импорте, который вроде как и нужен:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

Выскакивает сообщение, что импорт почему-то не используется:

```
The import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions is never used
```

При всем вышеописанном метод `assertEquals` импортируется нормально и не подсвечивается.

**Вот весь класс:**

```
package ru.terentyev.t1testtask.services;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;


public class AnalysisServiceImplTest {
    
    private AnalysisServiceImpl analysisServiceImpl;
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Correct string as input must be analized correctly")
    public void givenCorrectInputString_whenEqual_thenCorrect() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        assertEquals("{\"b\":5,\"a\":3,\"c\":2,\"d\":1}", analysisServiceImpl.takeEntriesCount("daaabbbbbcc"));
        assertThat("{\"b\":2,\"a\":4,\"c\":2,\"d\":1}", not(equalTo(analysisServiceImpl.takeEntriesCount("daaabbbbbcc"))));
        
    }
}
```

Я совсем запутался. Надеюсь на помощь.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.terentyev</groupId>
    <artifactId>t1testtask</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>t1testtask</name>
    <description>Test task for T1Consalting</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20231013</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Кажется, нашел ответ - он устарел: https://jsparrow.github.io/rules/replace-j-unit-assert-that-with-hamcrest.html надо импортировать следующее: `import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;`